# How to hide the template name?

Tags: templates, drupal, hide

this is my local site: drupaltest1/

When I/anyother developer inspect my site they can recognize which theme I am using. I want to hide the theme being displayed on inspect elements an display the site name in the path. I searched google, but no luck. Anyone please help in achieving this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change the name of the theme to your sitename.

in sites/all/themes/ copy your theme folder and rename the folder
then replace the theme name in .info file and use find/replace in template.php and any other theme specific files as well. (notepad++ search in files works well)
upload and enable the new theme in Drupal

If you are not using a custom theme for your site, be sure to check the licensing/copyright to ensure renaming it isn't a violation - and updates may have issues so you could remove the project info and/or packing script info.

Comment: I tried the above, but when I inspect my project, i still get http://localhost/new/sites/all/themes/themename/style.css. But my requirement is when I inspect I should only find as http://mysitename/style.css.  How to achieve this?

Comment: If you did as I suggested the themename would now be the same as your site name so it would be localhost/new/sites/all/themes/sitename/style.css   Did you set it as default after making the changes and enabling?

Comment: Yes I did, your concept localhost/new/sites/all/themes/sitename/style.css is working fine but my requirement is:  mysitename.com/style.css How to do this?

Comment: see the section "adding external stylesheets" here: [link](https://www.drupal.org/node/171209).  Use their example, but omit the second argument of drupal_add_class() since it won't be external.  You would then have to have style.css hosted in the root directory.  Configuring CSS like this for a theme isn't best practice though, and is probably not recommended from a Drupal or theme manageability perspective, but will accomplish what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you can create a sub-theme, then you would be able to hide those info(s) from being inspected your site pages.

Please reply if this helped you.

https://www.drupal.org/node/1010576

https://www.drupal.org/node/225125